# strange exception in java sql update

Tags: java, sql, exception

I'm trying to edit a sql table using a java program. However, i get the following exception(includes stacktrace). The exception is a verystrange one, never encountered it before.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[,20,375,298x28,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmen' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1604)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1519)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1504)
at transaction.EditClientTrans.clEditTrActionPerformed(EditClientTrans.java:259)
at transaction.EditClientTrans.access$300(EditClientTrans.java:23)
at transaction.EditClientTrans$4.actionPerformed(EditClientTrans.java:121)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1651)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1603)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at transaction.EditClientTrans$5.run(EditClientTrans.java:310)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here is the code:

```
private void clEditTrActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        long bal = amtnum - downp;
        payoption = (String) payOpt.getSelectedItem();
        if(bal==0)
            pstat = "Fully Paid";
        else if((bal>0)&&(bal<amtnum))
            pstat = "Partially Paid";
        else if(bal==amtnum)
            pstat = "Unpaid";
        String sql = "update kusinanikambal.ctrans "
                + "set clname = '"+cliName.getText()
                +"', contdet = '"+cliCNo.getText()
                +"', date = '"+Date.getText()
                +"', amt = "+amtnum
                +",  paidamt= "+down
                +",  bal = "+bal
                +", paymethod = '"+payoption+"'"
                +", paystat = '"+pstat+"'"
                + "where transno = "+ transNo.getText();
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        int rs = pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Edit Successful");
        super.setVisible(false);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you console print out the sql string after it's been created? It would probably be easy to spot the syntax problem with that.

Comment: Do you need an extra space here + "where transno in between " and where

Comment: + " where transno = "+ transNo.getText();

Comment: printed it. saw the error. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: I see SQL injection attacks in your near future.  You're using a `PreparedStatement`, but you're not using it right.  Read up on this, please, it's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've appended an `Object` (in this, some kind of component) as part of your query, which has used the object's `toString` method as the result.  Can't tell which one as you've not provided that much information.

You should also consider using [`PreparedStatement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of appending the query `String` together...

Comment: +1 for the PreparedStatement bit, because the code as provided opens you up to SQL injections. If you don't know what those are, **read up on them**. They're a gaping security hole.

Comment: print the `sql` value out before trying to execute it to see the exact SQL you're trying to execute, then work out which object is causing the problem ...then read up on prepared statements.